# How to read file in jquery rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

want to display image which pass through from params and currently image names is show but i want to display it through jquery

```
prefill_verification_screen = ->
  $('#selected_plan').text($('#customer_application_plan_id option:selected').text())
  $('#selected_first_name').text($('#customer_application_first_name').val())
  $('#selected_last_name').text($('#customer_application_last_name').val())
  $('#selected_postal_address').text($('#customer_application_postal_address').val())
  $('#selected_physical_address').text($('#customer_application_physical_address').val())
  $('#selected_city').text($('#customer_application_city').val())
  $('#selected_date_of_birth').text($('#customer_application_date_of_birth').val())
  $('#selected_id_number').text($('#customer_application_id_number').val())
  $('#selected_designation').text($('#customer_application_designation').val())
  $('#selected_cell_phone').text($('#customer_application_cell_phone').val())
  $('#selected_work_phone').text($('#customer_application_work_phone').val())
  $('#selected_salutation').text($('#customer_application_salutation').val())
  $('#selected_marital_status').text($('#customer_application_marital_status').val())
  $('#selected_file').readAsDataURL($('#customer_application_file') .val())
```

and i am passing it through form

```
<% CustomerApplication.form_params.each do |field| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <p class='text-primary font-bold'><%= field.capitalize %></p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <p id='selected_<%= field %>' class='text-success font-italic'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```